# Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on **firebase** phone authentication, after receiving code on my phone number the code jumps to `verifysignincode()` method, it fails to create `phoneAuthCredentials`. The exception which program catches is "Cannot create `PhoneAuthCredential` without either `verificationProof`, `sessionInfo`, temporary proof, or enrollment ID."

This is my send code method:

```
    public void send_code(){
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            Log.d("code", "onCodeSent:" + s);
            verificationID=s;
        }
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthentication.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };
    mPhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
            user_contact , 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, PhoneAuthentication.this, mCallbacks
    );}
```

This is my verify sign in method:

```
    public void verifySignInCode(String code){
    try {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

this is my signin method with phone credentials:

```
    private  void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential){
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuthentication.this, UserHome.class));
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("error:", task.getException().getMessage());

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

ERROR:

> Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof,
>   sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.

Comment: Can you log the code your receiving ? i think it's smaller or bigger than 6 digits.

Comment: it happened with me when i ran three emulators at one time to check my app

Answer (score 3):

Problem: This has burned me quite a long and after researching I got to know that this happens due to either low memory on phone or low network connection. When you maintain log with verification id i.e. log.d(TAG, verificationId) it will show null in verificationId and as per the error it says cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without verification proof and verificationId is our verification proof.

Solution:

> 1. Clear phone cache and try signing again. Go to app info and clear cache.
> 2. Restore Instance State

```
private String verificationId;
private static final String KEY_VERIFICATION_ID = "key_verification_id";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);

    // Restore instance state
    // put this code after starting phone number verification
    if (verificationId == null && savedInstanceState != null) {
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}//end of onCreate

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_VERIFICATION_ID,verificationId);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    verificationId = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_VERIFICATION_ID);
}
```

What happens is the verificationId is stored locally and it is lost sometimes due to less memory. So to tackle this situation we have to restore Instance State which won't let the verificationId to be lost.

Comment: What is "key_verification_id" is this something you actually retrieve or do you just leave it like this exactly like in your example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with the same issue being reported in Firebase Crashlytics and Play Store pre-launch testing, but it only seems to happen when I launch the app on Google Play Store and it automatically tries to test the app on many different devices. So I'm thinking it's more an issue with that testing process. It doesn't seem to be happening to any real users. I could be wrong though, I just notice a spike in these errors only when I launch the app and it goes through that testing phase. The rest of the time, no such errors are reported.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

Comment: This is only for the Emulator and I don't think it is directly related to the reported error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some other devices were working fine so when I created the logs. I got 'verificationId' is getting null, and without verficationId or token, we are getting this issue.
So first I wasted so much time finding a solution. I read the complete official documentation. And in the end **when I changed my network from wifi to mobile data then it worked.**

Comment: wowwwwwww lmaooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some phone numbers and other numbers worked fine.

**to solve that delete your app data and cache then restart your phone.**

Answer (score 0):

Add your SHA code on firebase settings to your project. If already done, do the same again with the recent one. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be coming from this line (in `verifySignInCode` method):

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, code);
```

Try making `verificationID` static, given its a Global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void verifySignInCode(String code){
    try {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Here in this code you have to do changes don't try to call code here as a string instead try to call

```
editText.getText().toString().trim();
```

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, editText.getText().toString().trim());
```

I solved my problem by doing this hope it helps ....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have obtained the **verificationId** from Firebase Authentication by calling **verifyPhoneNumber** method and passed it as a parameter to your **verificationOTP** method. Also, ensure that the smsCode you are passing to PhoneAuthProvider.credential is not **empty** or **null**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in react native just like me, The reason was I was using the wrong phone no.

```
onPress={() => signInWithPhoneNumber('+1 650-555-3434')}
```

You have to use the device phone no.