# Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof,Enrollement ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a WhatsApp clone app which am following from a tutorial. Each time I try to click on my Send button to get a verification code from firebase, the app crashes and this is what I get

I have added the SHA1 to firebase and yet I get the same Thing. I have checked all the answers related to this error and yet.

Error Message Here:

```
Process: com.example.yoo, PID: 23390
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:7)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.0:36)
    at com.example.yoo.view.startup.auth.PhoneLoginActivity.verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(PhoneLoginActivity.java:181)
    at com.example.yoo.view.startup.auth.PhoneLoginActivity.access$400(PhoneLoginActivity.java:32)
    at com.example.yoo.view.startup.auth.PhoneLoginActivity$1.onClick(PhoneLoginActivity.java:88)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6177)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23223)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6295)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)









public class PhoneLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityPhoneLoginBinding binding;
private String TAG = "PhoneLoginActivity";

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;






private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private FirebaseFirestore firestore;


//    String[] country={"Nigeria","Germany","China","Japan","Israel"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_phone_login);




    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);



    binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {



            if (binding.btnNext.getText().toString().equals("Next")) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
                progressDialog.show();

                String phone = "+" + binding.edCodeCountry.getText().toString() + binding.edPhone.getText().toString();
                startPhoneNumberVerification(phone);
            } else {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Verifying..");
                progressDialog.show();
            

            }
        }

    });

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {


        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull  PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted : Complete");
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull  FirebaseException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationFailed :" + e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override

        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,

                               @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

         

            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);


            
            mVerificationId = verificationId;

            mResendToken = token;


            binding.btnNext.setText("Confirm");
            progressDialog.dismiss();

           

        }

    };
```

Continue here

```
  private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Send code to:" + phoneNumber);
    progressDialog.show();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this, mCallbacks
    );
}

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {

    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);

    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}







private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            

            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override

                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {



                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredentials: success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                      


                       

                    } else {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();



                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {


                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete : ERROR CODE");


                        }


                    }

                }

            });

}
```

Comment: There is proper answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020954/10182897) problem

Comment: @Ashish I have tried that too but dosent work

Comment: What do you mean by "added the SHA1 to firebase", shouldn't it be SHA-256 if you are talking about the [verification fingerprint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification).

Comment: Also using `verifyPhoneNumber(String, long, TimeUnit, Activity, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)` is deprecated. Use the [`verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneAuthOptions)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) method instead.

Comment: tried  that and yet no change  @samthecodingman

Comment: Hi, others users have managed to find a workaround to this problem [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1392). Also you can post it there your issue too.